# matplotlib xlim TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

this is the original repo i'm trying to run in my computer: https://github.com/kreamkorokke/cs244-final-project

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
from attacker import check_attack_type

IMG_DIR = "./plots"

def read_lines(f, d):
    lines = f.readlines()[:-1]
    for line in lines:
        typ, time, num = line.split(',')
        if typ == 'seq':
            d['seq']['time'].append(float(time))
            d['seq']['num'].append(float(num))
        elif typ == 'ack':
            d['ack']['time'].append(float(time))
            d['ack']['num'].append(float(num))
        else:
            raise "Unknown type read while parsing log file: %s" % typ

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Plot script for plotting sequence numbers.")
    parser.add_argument('--save', dest='save_imgs', action='store_true',
                        help="Set this to true to save images under specified output directory.")
    parser.add_argument('--attack', dest='attack',
                        nargs='?', const="", type=check_attack_type,
                        help="Attack name (used in plot names).")
    parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output_dir', default=IMG_DIR,
                        help="Directory to store plots.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    save_imgs = args.save_imgs
    output_dir = args.output_dir
    attack_name = args.attack

    if save_imgs and attack_name not in ['div', 'dup', 'opt'] :
        print("Attack name needed for saving plot figures.")
        return

    normal_log = {'seq':{'time':[], 'num':[]}, 'ack':{'time':[], 'num':[]}}
    attack_log = {'seq':{'time':[], 'num':[]}, 'ack':{'time':[], 'num':[]}}
    normal_f = open('log.txt', 'r')
    attack_f = open('%s_attack_log.txt' % attack_name, 'r')
    
    read_lines(normal_f, normal_log)
    read_lines(attack_f, attack_log)
   
    if attack_name == 'div':
        attack_desc = 'ACK Division'
    elif attack_name == 'dup':
        attack_desc = 'DupACK Spoofing'
    elif attack_name == 'opt':
        attack_desc = 'Optimistic ACKing'
    else:
        raise 'Unknown attack type: %s' % attack_name
    norm_seq_time, norm_seq_num = normal_log['seq']['time'], normal_log['seq']['num']
    norm_ack_time, norm_ack_num = normal_log['ack']['time'], normal_log['ack']['num']
    atck_seq_time, atck_seq_num = attack_log['seq']['time'], attack_log['seq']['num']
    atck_ack_time, atck_ack_num = attack_log['ack']['time'], attack_log['ack']['num']
    plt.plot(norm_seq_time, norm_seq_num, 'b^', label='Regular TCP Data Segments')
    plt.plot(norm_ack_time, norm_ack_num, 'bx', label='Regular TCP ACKs')
    plt.plot(atck_seq_time, atck_seq_num, 'rs', label='%s Attack Data Segments' % attack_desc)
    plt.plot(atck_ack_time, atck_ack_num, 'r+', label='%s Attack ACKs' % attack_desc)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

    x = max(max(norm_seq_time, norm_ack_time),max(atck_seq_time, atck_ack_time))
    y = max(max(norm_seq_num, norm_ack_num),max(atck_seq_num, atck_ack_num))
    plt.xlim(0, x)
    plt.ylim(0,y)

    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Sequence Number (Bytes)')

    if save_imgs:
        # Save images to figure/
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)
        plt.savefig(output_dir + "/" + attack_name)
    else:
        plt.show()
    
    normal_f.close()
    attack_f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

after running this i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "plot.py", line 66, in main
    plt.xlim(0, a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1427, in xlim
    ret = ax.set_xlim(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 3267, in set_xlim
    reverse = left > right
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
Done! Please check ./plots for all generated plots.
```

how can i solve this problem? or better yet if there is another way of running this project? i installed matplotlib via pip3 install matplotlib command (same with scapy) and my main python version is python2 right now but i run the project with python3, could the issue be about this? what am i missing?  or is it about mininet itself?

Comment: The line `plt.xlim(0, a)` does not exist in your code but I assume it has something to do with the `max` functions. I suggest you `print(a)` and see if it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
 x = max(max(norm_seq_time, norm_ack_time),max(atck_seq_time, atck_ack_time))
```

IIUC, you wanna assign to `x` the maximum value among all those four lists. However, when you pass two lists to the `max` function, such as `max(norm_seq_time, norm_ack_time)`, it will return the list it considers the greater one, and not the highest value considering both lists.

Instead, you can do something like:

```
x = max(norm_seq_time + norm_ack_time + atck_seq_time + atck_ack_time)
```

This will concatenate the four lists into a single one. Then, the function will return the highest value among all of them. You might wanna do that to the calculation of `y` as well.

If this is not what you wanted, or if you have any further issues, please let us know.

Comment: thank you for your answer now i get this error again: ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
Done! Please check ./plots for all generated plots. 
could you help me?

Comment: If you check the [repository](https://github.com/kreamkorokke/cs244-final-project/blob/master/plot.py) you'll see that the code is slightly different. You can try, `x = [0, max((max(norm_seq_time), max(norm_ack_time), max(atck_seq_time), max(atck_ack_time)))]`

Comment: unfortunetly that didnt work that's why i was trying to change the code and see if it works

Comment: Did it throw an error? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of a friend we solved this problem by changing a part in code into this:

````
    max_norm_seq_time = max(norm_seq_time) if len(norm_seq_time) > 0 else 0
    max_norm_ack_time = max(norm_ack_time) if len(norm_ack_time) > 0 else 0    

    max_atck_seq_time = max(atck_seq_time) if len(atck_seq_time) > 0 else 0
    max_atck_ack_time = max(atck_ack_time) if len(atck_ack_time) > 0 else 0

    x =  max((max_norm_seq_time, max_norm_ack_time,\
                      max_atck_seq_time, max_atck_ack_time))
    plt.xlim([0,x])

    max_norm_seq_num = max(norm_seq_num) if len(norm_seq_num) > 0 else 0
    max_norm_ack_num = max(norm_ack_num) if len(norm_ack_num) > 0 else 0    

    max_atck_seq_num = max(atck_seq_num) if len(atck_seq_num) > 0 else 0
    max_atck_ack_num = max(atck_ack_num) if len(atck_ack_num) > 0 else 0
    plt.ylim([0, max((max_norm_seq_num, max_norm_ack_num,\
                      max_atck_seq_num, max_atck_ack_num))])
    ```
writing here just in case anyone else needs it.
````